# Max match same numbers from each row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

To generate 1mln rows of report with the below mentioned script is taking almost 2 days so, really appreciate if somebody could help me with different script which the report can be generated within 10-15mins please.

The requirement of the report is as following;

Table “cover” contains 5mln rows & 6 columns of data and likewise table “data” contains 500,000 rows and 6 columns.

So, each numbers of the rows in table cover has to go through table date and provide the maximum matches.

For instance, as mentioned on the below tables, there could be 3 matches in row #1, 2 matches in row #2 and 5 matches in row #3 so the script has to select the max selection which is 5 in row #3.

[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ki2W.png)

```
UPDATE public.cover_sheet AS fc 
  SET maxmatch = (SELECT MAX(tmp.mtch) 
                  FROM (
                    SELECT (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.a=drwo.a THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                           (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.b=drwo.b THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                           (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.c=drwo.c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
                           (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.d=drwo.d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                           (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.e=drwo.e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                           (SELECT CASE WHEN fc.f=drwo.f THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mtch 
                    FROM public.data AS drwo
                  ) AS tmp) 
WHERE fc.code>0;

SELECT * 
FROM public.cover_sheet AS fc 
WHERE fc.maxmatch>0;
```

Comment: Too much SELECT!!! What DBMS?

Comment: It's totally unclear what this is supposed to do. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I have edited the question with some clarifications so, appreciate if you could provide a script to solve my requirements plz

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in the comment to the question, your question is not clear...

Seems, you want to get the number of records which 6 fields from both tables are equal.

I'd suggest to:

1. reduce the number of `select` statements, then the speed of query execution will increase,
2. split your query into few smaller ones (good practice), to check your logic,
3. use `join` to get equal data, see: [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
4. use subquery or [cte](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/) to get result on which you'll be able to update table.

I think you want to get result as follow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) mtch
FROM public.cover_sheet AS fc INNER JOIN public.data AS drwo ON 
    fc.a=drwo.a AND fc.b=drwo.b AND fc.c=drwo.c AND fc.d=drwo.d AND fc.e=drwo.e AND fc.f=drwo.f
```

If i'm not wrong and above query is correct, the time of execution of above query will reduce to about 1-2 minutes.

Finally, update query may look like:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    -- proper select statement here
)
UPDATE public.cover_sheet AS fc 
    SET maxmatch = qry.<fieldname>
FROM qry
WHERE fc.code>0 AND fc.<key> = qry.<key>;
```

---

**Note:**

*I do not see your data and i know nothing about its structure, relationships, etc. So, you have to change above query to your needs.*

---

Comment: thanks for the response,I have edited the question with some clarifications so, appreciate if you could provide a script to solve my requirements plz